# How to get string format link url .html in array using preg_match?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$array = array(
   1 => "tag/gomobi.html", 
   2 => "game.html", 
   3 => "game.php", 
   4 => "game.html", 
   5 => "game/game-mobile/feed.html"
);
foreach ($array as $url) {
   if(preg_match('/^((.*)\.html)(.*?)$/', $url, $matches)) {
       echo $matches[1].'<br />';    
   } 
}
```

But result can't remove value same (game.html)

```
tag/gomobi.html
game.html
game.html
game/game-mobile/feed.html
```

How to fix it, with result is:

```
tag/gomobi.html
game.html
game/game-mobile/feed.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$array = array(
   1 => "tag/gomobi.html", 
   2 => "game.html", 
   3 => "game.php", 
   4 => "game.html", 
   5 => "game/game-mobile/feed.html"
);

print_r (array_unique($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_unique();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). It removes duplicate values from an array

`print_r(array_unique($array));`